# Wordpress htaccess rewriterule - reading subfolders

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to have rewrite rule for `wp-content/uploads` folder and all sub-folders, and I am using next code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How i can reach through all sub-folders?

This code only works for files that going in `uploads/` not in subfolders like `/2017/06/1.jpg` or something like that.

Help me please, i am newbie in regex.
Thanks!

Comment: you are redirecting to a file named `download.php` with a `file` parameter. When you say your regex doesn't work for subfolders, this is not true, their path is just transmitted into the `file` string. Now, what do you want: to be redirected to subfolders (and have a `download.php` in every subfolder) OR that the subfolder is transmitted as a second parameter to a single `download.php` file? (this is partially already the case, just that path and file are mixed)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. The main thing that I want, it's to have access to dynamic folders, I have many images - wp-content/uplodad/2017/06 - how to set 2017/06 dynamic? I need to have access to file that will be in dynamic folders. It will be images only.

Comment: in your regex, `(.*)` means 'any character, unlimited number of times'. The round brackets mean that this expression is captured (and feeded into the `$1` of the rewritten url). So actually, anything in the url after the `wp-content/uploads/` will be transmitted to the `file` GET var in `download.php`. If you go to `wp-content/uplodad/2017/06/1.jpg`, the file var will contain `2017/06/1.jpg`. this is already dynamic (depends what you do in the php file)

Comment: Strange, because download.php fired only for files that in /uploads, not for sub-folders :(

Comment: maybe because of the way the var `file` is used in `download.php`? some functions need the file name separated from the path, that could lead to a silent error..

Comment: require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;

$file = $_GET["file"]; , i am just try to take this file + i am using die(); to understand we are in downloads.php or not. We have any way to add dynamic subfolders ?

Comment: should work with the code you just added, the problem must be after. Maybe i could help if i have the rest of the file, but in this context, i don't see what you mean by "dynamic folder". In theory, whatever you put in the url is feeded to the `file` var, which would be dynamic enough (for me)

Comment: Thanks, but not working, i have die() after file.

Comment: maybe you can give me some advice? I need any way to load custom php file when user have direct accesss to image file, jpg or png. Thanks